# Flask server sends socket message to JS only once

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, flask, socket.io

So I have a Flask server setup which emits text data in the form of sockets (using socketio). I have coded it such that upon connection, 1 socket is sent both ways i.e., from JS to python and another from python to JS. But when I call the same function that was used to send the socket to JS (send_message()), JS never receives the socket anymore.

Here is my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

connected_clients = {}

# Route for serving HTML
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('new.html')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(text, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(text))
    send_message("how may i help you")

def send_message(message, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    socketio.emit('message', message)
    print("sent data ", message)


def start_flask_app():
    socketio.run(app)

def start_assistant():
    import assistant_main as am
    am.launch_assistant()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=start_flask_app)
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=start_assistant)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
```

and here is my HTML+JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
</head>
<h1>THIS IS A WEBPAGE</h1>

<body>
</body>
<script>
    const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
    socket.connect(); // connect to the socket

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log("connection found")
        // once connected, send a socket back to python
        socket.emit('my event', {
            data: 'User Connected'
        });
    });

    socket.on('my response', function (msg) {
        console.log("my response: ", msg)
    })

    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log('Received message:', message);
    });
</script>

</html>
```

At first, I was only trying to send sockets one way, Python to JS, using the same send_message(text) function but it didn't work. Then I tried sending socket from JS to python which worked.
So I set it up in such a way that upon connection, a socket is sent and received on both ends using the same send_message() function. I added print() statements to the same function to make sure the function was being called. The function is only called when the connection is established other than that, doesn't matter how many times you call the function, JS never receives the socket.
PS: the send_message() is called by another python running on thread2 which generates text queries and passes it in to this function as follows :
*the flask server file is named as "server.py"

```
from server import send_message as say
def speak(text):
    say(str(text))
```